# C# TimeOnly value to localtime

Tags: c#, time

I am trying to change TimeOnly value to local TimeOnly.
What is the best way to do this in .NET? There isn't built in method to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: I'd think you'd need the date as well to handle daylight savings time.  Otherwise you're just looking at adding or subtracting whatever the local time difference is from UTC (or whatever time zone the current time is suppose to be in).

Comment: This operation is inherently problematic because `TimeOnly` represent a time of day. What if the time of day is `01:00` and the time zone offset is 2 hours? Should the time of day then just become `23:00`, even though that's the time of the *previous* day? There is no built-in method because you have to think about exactly what you're going for here first, then you can convert to `DateTime` as appropriate.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This could make sense if it's translating a UTC TimeOnly to Local for a daily time vs a time that occurs on a single day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of several issues, including daylight savings, varying calendar systems for different cultures, and differing leap second observation systems, local time *has no meaning* unless you also know the date. You **need** a date as part of the value or you can't really know what time to use for a given local timezone.

Comment: It may be possible in places that don't observe daylight savings.